# What I should use for chained payment, which provides me same functionality as PayPal adaptive payment?

Tags: node.js, paypal, stripe-payments, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I want same functionality same as PayPal delayed chained payment by using Adaptive payments.
In which Admin can hold buyers money and cut their commision and after that admin will release that payment to the seller, as we know PayPal stops supporting Adaptive Payments for new integrations so I can't use that one.
Please suggest if there is any payment gateway with this functionality.

Comment: What you want is to use https://stripe.com/docs/connect with Custom or Express accounts https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts

Comment: @koopajah Can we hold money before it is paid to seller? And what about transaction fees?

Comment: Yes you can do all this, it's all covered in details in the docs I linked. It's not really a coding question and more "how do I use Stripe" so I would recommend talking to their support team: https://support.stripe.com/email

Answer (score -1):

You Can use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) for the same.